# Как правильно пишется "инструменты для дистрибьюторов"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, как правильно пишется "инструменты для дистрибьюторов" или "инструменты дистрибьюторов"?"

Answer (score 1):

В Сети можно встретить выражение "инструмент для работы дистрибьюторов", например: "Ежедневник для планирования и самоконтроля является самым важным из всех инструментов для работы дистрибьюторов". Здесь использование предлога ДЛЯ не вызывает сомнения.

В принципе возможны оба варианта записи: "инструменты для дистрибьюторов" и "инструменты дистрибьюторов", но они имеют немного разные смысловые оттенки .

ИНСТРУМЕНТ ДИСТРИБЬЮТОРОВ - здесь определительное значение слова "дистрибьюторов" выступает на первый план, подчеркивается  присущее качество, свойственность, характерная профессиональная направленность тех приемов, которые называют инструментом. В данном случае речь идет, скорее, о  значении слова "инструмент как о 
способе, средстве, применяемом для достижения чего-л.

ИНСТРУМЕНТ ДЛЯ ДИСТРИБЬЮТОРОВ - здесь предложное управление Р.п. имеет достигательное значение цели, практически идет дублирование выражения "инструмент для работы дистрибьюторов".

Думается, что выражения равноправны с точки зрения смысла, хотя и имеют разную грамматическую форму.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ зависит от контекста. Могут быть инструменты, предназначенные для дистрибьюторов, и инструменты, используемые дистрибьюторами.

Сравните:

*Разработан новый инструмент для дистрибьюторов.*

*Наиболее популярны следующие инструменты дистрибьюторов...*